# Article explaining Fortuna algorithm

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, fortuna

Does anyone know an article that explains Fortuna algorithm for people without cryptographical background? If not, I would like to have an explanation because I don't manage to understand it.

Comment: Anything unclear after reading [Bruce Schneier's page](https://www.schneier.com/academic/fortuna/) and it's links, in particular [this](https://www.schneier.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fortuna.pdf#page=8) ? Also [this](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/03/the_security_of_7.html).

Comment: I mean, for example, what is the input, what is the output?

Comment: Excluding things of internal use, the input is $s$ "New or additional seed" fed to the ["Reseed" procedure](https://www.schneier.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fortuna.pdf#page=11). What that $s$ is depends on usage context, and is not part of the Fortuna algorithm. It can be things like the time (in some small unit) of events like keystrokes, disk delivering requested data...

Comment: I don't understand the difference between entropy accumulator and entropy pool

Comment: Fortuna's has one entropy accumulator comprising 32 pools. The difference is like between a bucket of apples and an apple (notice that there is a more to a bucket of apples than the apples). Note: I don't feel I know/understand Fortuna well enough to answer the question, which requires making a digest of [this](https://www.schneier.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fortuna.pdf#page=8). The entropy accumulators that I use in my applications are simpler, in particular because they do not attempt to save entropy from earlier "boots" of the system, which is part of the great complexity of Fortuna.